# AlarmManager change user data

Tags: android

Ok, I want to create a counter to show after user click something

think like iMobster, where after you click something you'll have a 5 mins timer and after that it'll increase your HP by 1...

To be honest I don't know how to code it using AlarmManager or anything else better, plus If let's say the alarm is running and the user lost another HP that means you'll have to add another AM for another 5 mins...

Maybe someone got better logic for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use AlarmManager for this. AlarmManager should be used for cases where you know in advance the specific time/date you want your code to execute; instead, you want to execute some code N minutes from *now*, which you'd do with a Handler and postDelayed.

```
mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, NUMBER_OF_MILLISECONDS);
```

And then define your Runnable as an instance in your class:

```
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do the work you want to do, like check if you need to add hitpoints or whatever

        // go again later (only necessary if you want to keep polling repeatedly)
        mHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, NUMBER_OF_MILLISECONDS);
    }
};
```

If you wanted to only run once, you'd omit the postDelayed() call from the code inside your Runnable. So maybe you'd call a postDelayed() on your Handler each time an action is taken that you want to add or subtract hitpoints for, and after the specified amount of time has passed it'd execute and be done.

Comment: seems logical, didn't check it yet, but will do later for sure.. does this insure that it'll be running even if the app get closed? (you know, same on those type of games)

Comment: Only if you put this code in a Service. Then it will continue running even if the app is closed.